# can't receive mails to thunderbird via postfix local server

Tags: postfix, thunderbird

A small introduction. I have a SMTP server ( Haraka - http://haraka.github.io/ ) on port 25 and a local postfix server on port 9267. I intercepts mails in Haraka and then I send them to my postfix server. I can see the mails received using mail -u username command but I want to use a email client(Thunderbird) to have access to them. I've created an account in Thunderbird via this https://askubuntu.com/questions/192572/how-read-local-email-in-thunderbird , but without any result and I think the problem is the postfix server configuration.
Here is my postfix main.cf file .

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache


#transport test
#transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = mydomain.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = mydomain.com, localhost.mydomain.com, localhost
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: I think I found the problem. I should use dovecot or something similar.

Comment: No you need not. If you can access mails using `mail` command, then there should be no issue with postfix. You should locate your mail file, where postfix is writing the mail to.

Comment: Ok, So I know there are 2 mail locations , one being /var/mail and the other one /var/spool/mail. In Thunderbird, at Server Settings - > Local Directory , I've put the first path without any result(no email showing). If I try to put the /var/spool/mail path , the setting goes back to /var/mail. Does anybody know why?

Comment: This should help https://commons.lbl.gov/display/~jwelcher@lbl.gov/Reading+an+mbox+file+with+Thunderbird

Comment: If I open that folder , it gives me the mails of my main account I have set up( like intenesi@gmail.com, btw it's not my address) but I have an account created for the mails that are landing in my local postfix , like test@localhost.com and I want to open this mails , not the ones from gmail. If you dont understand, I want to send mails from gmail and receive them in postfix, where I'd like to see them via Thunderbird.